# "No suitable XML Schema Validator could be found"

Tags: java, android, linux

Whilst trying to update through the Android AVD Manager, I receive the message:

*"No suitable XML Schema Validator could be found in your Java environment"*

It therefore can't parse the repository.xml and I can't download any updates.

How can I get rid of this error? I am guessing it might be caused by GIJ being the default Java implementation on my platform (Debian), however I have also installed the Sun JRE/JDK now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! Although I had installed the Sun JVM, **update-java-alternatives** needed to be run to switch the Java environment.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, had to do with the jvm.
check
   java -version

Do not install gcj/gij (obsolete GNU Java) or remove it if installed.
Use sun's jdk, or icedtea instead.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a number of things.

- It might be that your path to the SDK isn't set, or is wrong. In Preference > Android > SDK-location you should have a valid path.
- There might also be difficulties using HTTPS (https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) for updates. I have had this problem almost every time. Try changing to HTTP (http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/) and see if it works.
- Make sure all steps of the [install](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html) is completed. There is also some help on [updates](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#updating).

Good luck!